# Custom Leonardo board no USB?

Tags: arduino, usb

I have made my own version of the Leonardo, and I am having USB issues. Plugging it in to a windows computer - nothing happens! If I hold down reset, I get the "device not recognized error", but if I don't hold down reset, Windows acts like nothing is there.

Schematic: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/umxen.png)
[image]

Fuses
Extended: FB  (If I program it as CB, then press read again, it comes out as FB?)
High: D8
Low: FF

Using Caterina-Leonardo.hex, uploaded with AVR ISP MKII

The board itself is working, if I compile a blink sketch and flash it directly it works great. It's just that when I plug it into a computer, nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is going to be a dumb question, based on my ignorance of the platform, but are you certain that image provides USB connectivity?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Leonardo, but I'm under the impression that the bootloader makes the chip act as a virtual COM port, which allows you to upload code like a normal Arduino.

Comment: You should always have a pullup to VDD on the reset line. A common value is usually 4.7k or 10k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UCAP does not look right, it should not be connected to VCC, but to a capacitor to GND.

**edit**: I was rather tired when answering this yesterday, so I omitted the fact that I built my own Leonardo-style design recently, and correctly connecting UCAP made a big difference in getting USB working.

Comment: Thank you! As a quick fix I ripped off the UCAP pin. Now it shows up as "unknown device", which is progress!

Comment: Last update - turns out that UCAP pin with capacitor is absolutely critical to operation. Since disconnecting it wasn't enough, I wired in the 1uF cap to ground and now it works perfectly!